# TestNG swallows exception

Tags: java, exception, testng

In my method below when I get a IOException when I run it from TestNG (this is expected) but all I see is the InitConnectionException but not the cause. Anyone know why that is?

```
private void setupConnectionStreams(HttpsURLConnection connection) throws InitConnectionException {
    try {
        dataOutStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        dataInStream = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new InitConnectionException(e.getCause());
    }
}

public class InitConnectionException extends Exception{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public InitConnectionException(){
        super("There was a problem to setup a initialize a connection to the server.");
    }

    public InitConnectionException(String msg){
        super(msg);
    }

    public InitConnectionException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}




se.ports.epp.poolservice.client.transport.pool.connection.exceptions.InitConnectionException
    at se.ports.epp.poolservice.client.transport.pool.connection.impl.HttpsConnection.setupConnectionStreams(HttpsConnection.java:134)
    at se.ports.epp.poolservice.client.transport.pool.connection.impl.HttpsConnection.connect(HttpsConnection.java:84)
    at se.ports.connectionTests.HttpsConnectionTest.testGetHttpsConnectionToRegistry(HttpsConnectionTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:691)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:883)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1208)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:758)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:613)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:87)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1142)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:979)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:109)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:202)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:173)
FAILED: testGetHttpsConnectionToRegistry(PL)
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at se.ports.epp.poolservice.client.transport.pool.connection.impl.HttpsConnection.connect(HttpsConnection.java:87)
    at se.ports.connectionTests.HttpsConnectionTest.testGetHttpsConnectionToRegistry(HttpsConnectionTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:691)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:883)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1208)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:758)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:613)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:87)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1142)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:979)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:109)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:202)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:173)
```

Comment: Do you see something different outside of the test? Might it just be an IOException? What's that IllegalStateException?

Comment: What's the `InitConnectionException`? Can you post the code? This might not set the cause correctly.

Comment: Illegalstate is thrown after I catch the InitConnectionException in a calling method (this will be replace with the actual InitConnectionException once my refactor is done =)).